# How to correctly free nested data structures?

Tags: c, list, malloc, free

I have a small program which creates a linked list, the nodes of which house (pointers to) binary trees. When I exit the program I obviously want to deallocate this memory, I initially thought that I had to free all the tree nodes and the tree, and only then could I free the linked list members otherwise I'd be leaking memory. Is this incorrect? Do I only need to free the linked list nodes, and since these point to the binary trees the trees are automatically freed?

When I destroy the trees first, I get a crash trying to deallocate the list nodes, so I assume I should be just freeing the linked list, but I can't find a good source online for this so I thought I'd ask here.

Here's an excerpt of some of the code, the bit in question is the `destroy_list()` function, I just want to know if omitting the call to `destroy_tree()` will correctly free my memory.

```
typedef struct listNode
{
    char* name;
    BST* customers;
    struct listNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct list
{
    ListNode* head;
} List;

typedef struct bstnode
{
    long data;
    struct bstnode* left_node;
    struct bstnode* right_node;
} bstNode;

typedef struct bst
{
    bstNode* root;
} BST;

void destroy_list(List *self)
{
    ListNode* cursor = self->head;
    ListNode* prev = NULL;

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        prev = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
        destroy_tree(prev->customers);
        free(prev);
    }
    self->head = NULL;
}

void destroy_tree_node(bstNode* self)
{
    if (self == NULL)
        return;
    destroy_tree_node(self->left_node);
    destroy_tree_node(self->right_node);
    free(self);
}

void destroy_tree(BST* self)
{
    destroy_tree_node(self->root);
    free(self);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I just commented out the line, and it still crashes. I should've done some more investigation before posting a question, but I am going to leave it up since I am still interested in an answer to the question of whether the BST should be free'd independently of the list or not.

Comment: You don't really *have* to free dynamically allocated memory if you're going to exit right away, but doing so makes your code more flexible for future additions.  If you want to free it all, then you have to free each pointer that was returned by `malloc`, `realloc`, etc.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @Tom Karzes This was something I always wondered actually. I always assumed that memory should be released on program exit, but it's always stressed at university to free dynamically allocated memory so I was unsure. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @EOF I'm not asking for help code debugging per se, so I'm not sure how a MCV example is helpful here. I provided the code to give an idea of what I was trying to accomplish, not for readers to compile.

Comment: Another reason to do so is to make it easier to use tools that look for memory leaks.

Comment: @espionn Either you're asking a question about memory menagement *in general* (what to `free()`, for example), in which case you do not need to post *any* code (least of all the code you have posted), or you're asking about your *specific* code and why it crashes, in which case you very much need to post a [MCVE]. Choose one.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting the call to `destroy_tree` will not free your memory.

I see only two possibilities. Either `destroy_tree` needs to be armored against `NULL` or you have heap corruption elsewhere. Armor like so:

```
void destroy_tree(BST* self)
{
    if (!self) return;
    destroy_tree_node(self->root);
    free(self);
}
```